# Getting unidentified from bodyParser

Tags: html, node.js, express, handlebars.js, body-parser

I'm just starting learning nodejs + express + handlebars and I'm having a difficult time with my post. This is the request body that I am receiving and I can't seem to get the "province and municipality" data using req.body.province and req.body.municipality, but with bearing, I can.

```
{
'province ': 'ALBAY',
  'municipality ': 'BACACAY',
  bearing: '>=1 and <=20'
}
```

This is how I get my data from my form for municipality and province.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for='municipality'>Municipality</label> <select type= "text" name="municipality " class="form-control"> {{#each municipality}}
 <option>{{municipality}}</option> 
{{/each}} </select>
```

And this is for bearing.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="bearing">Bearing Trees</label> <select type="text" name="bearing" class="form-control">
 <option>>=1 and <=20</option>
<option>>=21 and <=50</option>
<option>>=51 and <=100</option> <option>>100</option> </select> </div>
```

I'm kinda stuck now and I need your help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i can see, the keys corresponding to municipality and province contains a space at the end.

Inside an object all the keys are of type string, which means the space is included unless you are using a symbole.

For your question it's more a typo that anything else.

your object should looks like this :

```
{
    province: 'ALBAY',
    municipality: 'BACACAY',
    bearing: '>=1 and <=20'
}
```

Comment: ohh. so that's why. i didnt notice that little space from the name. I've been stuck here for hours just for that error. Thank you very much!

Comment: my pleasure ahah ;)

Comment: you must update the name from your form, that's where the spaces come from

Comment: I just did that and finally made a progress in my app. I can parse the data now using bodyParser. thanks.

Comment: my pleasure, you can mark the question as resolved now